# How to find if a package is inside a package?

Tags: python, fast-ai

for example, the compose package is inside fastai.train

so I could not do

```py
from fastai import compose
```

rather I had to do

```py
from fastai.train import compose
```

how do I search where is a particular package is in?

Comment: Documentation. If that's missing, source code.

Comment: How do you know a function `compose` exists in the first place? Likely you've found it in documentation/examples/tutorials somewhere, no? Those should also show where to import it from exactly.